# Getting the Primary key of the row which can not be parsed

Tags: json, azure-sql-database, json-value

I am trying to parse a json value from a column in Azure Sql Database with the following query

```
select Key, JSON_VALUE(JsonField, '$.Total') 
from MyTable
```

However I am encountering some error in parsing that produces the following message

```
[12:37:32]  Started executing query at Line 12

    Msg 13609, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 0.
```

Is there any way to understand which rows have the following problem by, for example, having the column set to NULL by default in the return?

This way I can make a direct check on the resulting field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the T-SQL `ISJSON` function to identify problem values:

```
SELECT
      Key
    , JsonField
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE ISJSON(JsonField) = 0;
```